# Angular-Charts not rendering

Tags: javascript, angularjs

hello I am trying to just render a simple example from the Angular-Charts website and I cant even get it to render. I am assuming because my Angular directive is not loading or something.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/dist/angular-chart.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/angular.css"/>
</head>
<body>

<canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line" chart-data="data"
        chart-labels="labels" chart-legend="true" chart-series="series"
        chart-click="onClick" >
</canvas>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.1/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/dist/angular-chart.js"></script>
<script src="js/chart.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**chart.js**

```
angular.module("app", ["chart.js"]).controller("LineCtrl", function ($scope) {

    $scope.labels = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"];
    $scope.series = ['Series A', 'Series B'];
    $scope.data = [
        [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
        [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
    ];
    $scope.onClick = function (points, evt) {
        console.log(points, evt);
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to link up your angular with the project.

`<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="LineCtrl">
...
</body>`

Comment: Error: Invalid isolate scope definition for directive chartLine: =?
    at Error (native)
    at

Comment: You've got a fairly outdated version of angular - try an updated CDN [https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js)